# worpress не находит файлы с названиями на кириллице

Tags: wordpress

С помощью дополнительного поля добавляю файл. Если добавляю файл с названием на латинице, потом могу его скачать, но если на кириллице, то происходит: "Ошибка: файл отсутствует" (смотри скрин). Как решить данную проблему

```
<a href="<?php echo get_field( "price_file" )['url']?>" download>Прайс полного перечня работ</a>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит в инспекторе в браузере ссылка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: WordPress точно ни при чем. Возможно, установлен плагин транслитерации ссылок? И в любом случае, покажите, как выглядит ссылка в инспекторе браузера

Comment: Добавил изображение

Comment: Должно работать. Возможно, локальный сервер настроен неправильно.

Comment: Кодировки же. Файл наверняка создан в винде в 1251(или 1252), а сервер или   ВП кириллицу перекодирует в utf8. Или же сервер работает не в UTF8. В общем причин много. Доводов НЕ использовать кириллицу ещё больше. Разве что  если хочется приключений на седалищный нерв.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не критично, что имя файла после загрузки на сайт будет на латинице, то можно установить какой-нить плагин для транслитерации, например, [DCO Russian Fixes](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/dco-russian-fixes/).
Должно помочь.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно работает